# How to invoke the adapter(SQL or HTTP) call for every few seconds in IBM MobileFirstPlatform

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

In my application(using JQueryMobile) I am invoking the SQL Adapter call for getting the data from the enterprise database and storing in the JSONStore in my mobile app, now I need to update the real time data automatically in JSONStore whenever the enterprise DB is updated, without disturbing the mobile UI(means not showing that the JSONStore is refreshing). Please give me suggestions on this. If any feature is already available in MFP, then suggest the sample or tutorial in IBMKC. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to MobileFirst.

It does sound like you want to implement `setInterval`.
See usage examples here: http://www.sitepoint.com/setinterval-example/

Simply call whichever function you have to sync the JSONStore and don't do anything in the callbacks that will interfere with the application's UI.